# Update a String in an NSCoding/NSObject Array using Swift 2

Tags: swift2, nscoding

I have an iOS Project I'm working on using Xcode and Swift2.  I have a `class` that is of type `NSObject` and `NSCoding`:

```
class ReportDetails: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var fileName: String

    static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("details")

    struct PropertyKey {

        static let fileNameKey = "fileName"

    }

    init?(fileName: String) {

        self.fileName = fileName

        super.init()

        if fileName.isEmpty {

            return nil

        }

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encodeObject(fileName, forKey: PropertyKey.fileNameKey)

    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let fileName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.fileNameKey) as! String

        self.init(fileName: fileName)

    }    

}
```

This is then shown in a `Tableview` showing the `fileName` in the `TableViewCell`s.  It writes to it fine using a `UITextField` and `UIButton` to submit and saving (`NSCoding`) the user typed item into the `array` and reloading the `TableView` so the user see's it.

The `@IBAction` for the `UIButton` includes:

```
self.fileName = nameTextField.text

let report = ReportDetails(fileName: self.fileName)
self.details.append(report!)
```

`details` is `var details = [RecipeDetails]()` outside of the `@IBAction` code.

I have a way for the user to rename the `fileName` using a `UITextField`, but when I go to `append` it, it simply creates a new one.  How I can update the name and save it to the array, if the user wants too.  Is there something else to use besides `.append` for simply updating? Or is `NSCoding` a write only type of save?  Just a simple rename and save using `NSCoding` is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably i don't understand your problem. As I see, you wold like to update property of class 'saved' in Swift array. I don't see any relation to NSObject or NSCoding there.

```
class C {
    var txt: String
    init(txt: String) {
        self.txt = txt
    }
}

var arr: [C] = []

arr.append(C(txt: "a"))
arr.append(C(txt: "b"))
dump(arr)
/*
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ [0]: C #0
    - txt: a
  ▿ [1]: C #1
    - txt: b
*/
```

Updating some property of instance of class 'stored' in the array is simple. You need to know position of the instance in the array (index) and new value of the property, that's all.

```
arr[0].txt = "A"
dump(arr)
/*
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ [0]: C #0
    - txt: A
  ▿ [1]: C #1
    - txt: b
*/
```

Comment: I added the rest of the NSCoding code.  My goal is to update a report name to a new one, via the user typing the new name in the `UITextField` and then pressing the `UIButton` called `Update`. This would take an old report name of let's say 'Inspection2015' and update it with a new name of 'Inspection2016' if that's what the user typed.  The `.append` creates a new report for 2016, not renaming the 2015 one.

Comment: @ChallengerGuy self.details.append(report!) add instance of ReportDetails class to the end of an existing Swift's array (or crash if report is nil). this function has nothing with NSCoding. how to update some property of an instance of ReportDetails which is 'saved' inside details array is shown in my snippet.

Comment: Ok, looking back at it and tweaking it a little works.  Thank you.